# GitLab API - get the overall # of lines of code

Tags: api, statistics, gitlab

I'm able to get the stats (additions, deletions, total) for each commit, however how can I get the overall #?
For example, if one MR has 30 commits, I need the net # of lines of code added\deleted which you can see in the top corner.
This # IS NOT the sum of all #'s per commit.
So, I would need an API that returns the net # of lines of code added\removed at MR level (no matter how many commits are).
For example, if I have 2 commits: 1st one adds 10 lines, and the 2nd one removes the exact same 10 lines, then the net # is 0.

---

Here is the scenario:
I have an MR with 30 commits.
GitLab API provides support to get the stats (lines of code added\deleted) per Commit (individually).
If I go in GitLab UI, go to the MR \ Changes, I see the # of lines added\deleted that is not the SUM of all the Commits stats that I'm getting thru API.
That's my issue.
A simpler example: let's say I have 2 commits, one adds 10 lines of code, while the 2nd commit removes the exact same 10 lines of code. Using the API, I'm getting the sum, which is 20 LOCs added. However, if I go in the GitLab UI \ Changes, it's showing me 0 (zero), which is correct; that's the net # of chgs overall. This is the inconsistency I noticed.

Comment: `IS NOT the sum of all #'s per commit` What you describe _is_ exactly the sum of all additions/deletions for each commit in the MR, so I'm a bit confused. I'm not sure I understand exactly what you're looking for, if what you're sure what you're looking for is **not** the sum of deletions and additions in all commits in the MR.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean now -- the key factor is when **the same lines** are removed in a subsequent commit. Let's say a commit removes **different** lines that were _not_ added from commits in the same MR, you want to count those. In other words, if the _effective_ change in a LOC is wiped away by another commit, you don't want to consider it in your line counts.

Comment: Yes, that's the issue; hopefully, someone has a solution for it.

Comment: I see now. While there isn't an API that gives you the count directly, you can calculate this from the diff yourself. I've added an answer with a complete working solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do this for an MR, you would use the [MR changes API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_requests.html#get-single-mr-changes) and count the occurrences of lines starting with `+` and `-` in the `changes[].diff` fields to get the additions and deletions respectively.

Using bash with [gitlab-org/gitlab-runner!3195](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/merge_requests/3195/diffs) as an example:

```sh
GITLAB_HOST="https://gitlab.com"
PROJECT_ID="250833"
MR_ID="3195"

URL="${GITLAB_HOST}/api/v4/projects/${PROJECT_ID}/merge_requests/${MR_ID}/changes"
DIFF=$(curl ${URL} | jq -r ".changes[].diff")
ADDITIONS=$(grep -E "^\+" <<< "$DIFF")
DELETIONS=$(grep -E "^\-" <<< "$DIFF")
NUM_ADDITIONS=$(wc -l <<< "$ADDITIONS")
NUM_DELETIONS=$(wc -l <<< "$DELETIONS")
echo "${MR_ID} has ${NUM_ADDITIONS} additions and ${NUM_DELETIONS} deletions"
```

The output is

```
3195 has 9 additions and 2 deletions
```

This matches the UI, which also shows 9 additions and 2 deletions

[image: GitLab-Runner MR 3195 diff UI]

This, as you can see is a representative example of your described scenario since the combined total of the *individual commits* in this MR are 13 additions and 6 deletions.

Comment: Thank you; definitely, you pointed me towards a very promising API.
However, using that API (get the changes per MR), as well as using CURL, I'm getting this info back:
MR diff:  -68,5 +68,6 
MR diff:  -667,13 +667,17 
MR diff:  -285,7 +285,7 
MR diff:  -50,7 +50,15 
MR diff:  -13,6 +13,7 
MR diff:  -1,7 +1,10 
MR diff:  -84,6 +84,8 
MR diff:  -21,6 +21,7 
MR diff:  -0,0 +1,59  
It seems it's tied to the # of files changed (in the above example, 9 files got changed  overall, part of several commits).
The syntax of the result is not as in GitLab API doc.

Comment: The GitLab API specifies "-1 +1" as diff answer.
What I'm observing, i.e.  -285,7 +285,7, I think it means that in the UI, the file snippet starts at LOC #285, and I presume 7 LOC got added, and 7 got removed, so the net is 0 (zero).
But, it's not matching the overall #'s shown in the UI top left.

Comment: @da75 without having the same MR you're using in front of me, it's hard for me to tell what you're describing. Can you provide a reproducible example that is public on gitlab.com?

Comment: Thanks; I don't have a public MR to provide; but, as per GitLab API, for "GET /projects/:id/merge_requests/:merge_request_iid/changes", I should get back among other data this "diff": "--- a/VERSION\ +++ b/VERSION\ @@ -1 +1 @@\ -1.9.7\, where I assume -1 +1 is what I need.
Instead for that cmd I get for example "-124,9 +124,6" plus the chgs themselves.
Do I have to set access_raw_diffs param one way or another?

Comment: No, the numbers after the `@@`  is **not** what you need. The script above as-is will do the right thing. You don't need to pass `access_raw_diffs` either. What the script is doing is counting the actual diff lines, which will all either start with `-` or `+`. Any line in the diff which starts with anything other than `-` or `+` is ignored (because they are either informational parts of the diff or unchanged lines of code) Are you using gitlab.com or self-hosted? If you're using self-hosted are you on the latest version of GitLab? If not, what version? @da75 Have you tried my script exactly?

Comment: oh la la! now I got it; the diff answer holds exactly what's shown in the UI: the lines removed have - in front, while the ones added have +; that's what we need to parse.
I'm doing it in C# using GitLab API.